# Do I need to uninstall Python 3.5 before installing Anaconda on OSX?

Tags: python, anaconda

I had some issues with matplotlib in virtualenvironments on Python and was recommended to uninstall 3.5 to install anaconda as a result. If so, do I need to `pip uninstall` everything (both globally and on my user) I see from `pip freeze` as well as everything I've installed with `brew`? Or will Anaconda be able to utilize what is already installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't need to uninstall anything.  Anaconda, including its own Python distribution, lives in a separate directory.  Anaconda adjusts the paths to make this work, so if some things relied on specifics of your old Python paths, those may break, but that's about all.

Comment: I see. By adjust the paths do you mean it modifies my bash_profile? In that case I could probably just save off my paths and restore them if I need to?

Comment: Yes, I think all of that is the case.